# Angular JS redirect to page within module config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular js module where all the routes are setup. I have defined a variable "maintenance". if this is set to true , I want the page to be redirected to maintenance page. I have setup the states using stateprovider.

I am trying to redirect using the code below -

```
if(maintenance){
    $state.go('maintenance');
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. However If I do the below , the redirect is successful -

```
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signup/productSelector');
```

I assume using "otherwise" may not be the correct solution in this case. How can I redirect?

**EDIT**

In the below example , I would like any call to app.html to be redirected to maintenance page irrespective of what is present after #.

```
https://<url>/app.html#/orders/resi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the state service within the config method since it is still being configured at that point.

If you'd like to specificly redirect right after the angular module is run then you could execute the $state.go in a .run function as follows:

```
angular.module("yourModule").run(['$state', function($state) {
    $state.go('maintenance');
}])
```

Or better yet you can force the redirection to happen after every state transition using the transition services:

```
angular.module("yourModule").run(['$transition', function($transition) {
    $transition.onBefore({}, function(transition) {
        var stateService = transition.router.stateService;
        if (maintenance && transition.to().name !== 'maintenance') {
            return stateService.target('maintenance');
        }
    })
}])
```

https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks

Comment: Thanks bramve. At the end of the config section , there is already a redirect which redirects to default page. Can't something similar be done?         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/defaultpage);

Comment: The otherwise function only works when a route does not get matched. but if i understand you correctly you want to force the redirection for every route. This is what the solution i mentioned does. Also i made a edit which adds another way to do it, it might be exactly what you want.

Comment: with second answer , is there a possibility that this transition block will be called when routing to maintenance state making it infinite call? if so , is there a way to exclude this being called for maintenance state?

Comment: @PunterVicky Ah yea forgot about that, i editted my awnser to fix the infinite loop

Comment: thanks , I did try the exact same solution but this didn't work too. Should any return statement be added outside the if block?

Comment: I now see an error "Unknown provider: $transitionsProvider <- $transitions"

Comment: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$transitionsProvider%20%3C-%20$transitions

Comment: Make sure to call it $transition without an s, otherwise the injection will indeed fail. Check out the transitionhooks documentation to see how it works in detail.

Comment: In the link that is provided , I see "transitions" in the examples that are provided. However I do see the same error for transition as well.

Comment: When I use $transition , I see this error : TypeError: $transition.onBefore is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the state service within a configure method. Instead if you'd like to redirect to a certain state after the angular module has been loaded you could do it in a .run function insteadn

```
angular.module().run(['$state' '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    if (maintanance) {
        // If logged out and transitioning to a logged in page:
        e.preventDefault();
         $state.go('maintenance');
    } 
});
```

Comment: oh woops, i send a edit for the wrong awnser sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks @Santosh Singh. At the end of the config section , there is already a redirect which redirects to default page. Can't something similar be done? $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/defaultpage);