# Redirecting to maintenance page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for ways of redirecting a page to the maintenance page in angular but i am new and am research different methods for turning on maintenance mode
i found a possible solution here: @ the approved answer
[Angular JS redirect to page within module config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302009/angular-js-redirect-to-page-within-module-config/49302188)

however i don't know how to implement it
if there someone who could explain it, i would appreciate it greatly

Comment: I decided not to take the ui-router method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using an authGuard will solve this problem

auth-guard.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardMaintenance implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService, private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.inMaintenance()) {
      alert('This Site Is Still Under Maintenance')
      this.router.navigate(['/maintenance']);
      return false;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

auth.service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  inMaintenance() {
    return false;
    }
}
```

then import it in the app.module.ts file and add it to providers

then import the auth guard to the app-routing.module.ts file add the property

```
canActivate: [AuthGuardMaintenance]
```

to the the root route
eg

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardMaintenance] },
  { path: 'maintenance', component: MaintenanceViewComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure in angular but I solved that issue using mod_rewrite.
htaccess

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} !='YOUR IP'">
 RedirectMatch ^/((?!mnt/foo.html).*)$ /mnt/foo.html
</If>
```